# At what exact date and location does Mercury appear at the highest altitude from Earth in history?

Tags: the-sun, mercury

I have been messing around with the elongation for Mercury, and I have been getting 27.8 degrees at maximum in https://www.heavens-above.com/PlanetSummary.aspx. Is there any history record that Mercury could go higher than 27.8 degrees or is 27.8 degrees the absolute maximum elongation that could be ever achieved?

Comment: The title asks about altitude, the text asks about elongation.  You should clarify which you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 27.8 is the maximum that can be achieved.  [jgiesen.de](http://www.jgiesen.de/skymap/MercuryVenus) calculates this from the eccentricity of the orbit of Mercury:

$$\sin β = a(1+e)/(1\, \text{AU})= 0.467,\ β = 27.8°$$

For Mercury a=0.387 and e=0.206.

You could make a small correction for the Earth's eccentricity, but this is very much less than the eccentricity of Mercury, so has less effect